# Cubic Gaussian Surface For Evaluating Electric Flux

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

i'm working through some problem sets about Gauss' law and all the examples I have come across so far require the use of a spherical gaussian surface for a point charge, so that it is possible to say the electric field lines are perpendicular to the surface. I feel confident in answering these.

If my gaussian surface is a cube, I don't understand how to find $\cos \phi$, since the field lines radiating out of my point charge pass through the surface at different angles to the normal.

Is there some assumption that can be made, or am I missing something obvious that allows me to evaluate this?

One idea i've had (but can't find any justification for in my text book) is that if you consider angles on one side of the normal positive, and negative on the other, they cancel out and you can consider the field lines to be going perpendicular through all the surfaces.

I hope my question is clear,

thanks!

Comment: That's why we *choose* a Gaussian surface in such a way that we know what $cos\phi$ is. Why *do* you want to use a cubical surface, though? And no, they won't cancel out because every point on the surface is at a different distance from the point charge.

Comment: I would much rather use a sphere, but the question wants me to use a cube.

I have just realised the answer to my question though. For a point charge $EA = \frac{q}{\epsilon_{0}}$ There is no need to know $\cos \phi$